# Htaccess Concatenarion

Tags: .htaccess, concatenation, minify

I use this code to concatenare CSS and Javascript:

```
<FilesMatch "\.combined\.js$">
  Options +Includes
  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES application/javascript application/json
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
  Options +Includes
  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</FilesMatch>
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: So you're using `<!--#include file="path/to/a/file.js" -->` in a master JS/CSS file?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt write properly the code. now is right.

Comment: Oh I understand! I had to write those directives in the combined file! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're using

```
<!--#include file="path/to/a/file.js" -->
<!--#include file="path/to/another/file.js" -->
```

in a master JS or CSS file, right?

This is what is being enabled by the `.htaccess` code posted in your question.

Comment: what needs to be enabled to make this work.... I used to work but now on my local ubuntu 12.04 it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I also used same code for concatenating my js and css file. It works pefectly in my local machine..but don't work in live. I am using ubutu linux server.